# Eclipse - playframework, angularjs and coffeescript

Tags: java, eclipse, angularjs, playframework, coffeescript

I have started a new project, where as a backend is playframework 2 and as a frontend is angularjs with coffeescript.
For everyday I am using Eclipse and I was looking for plugins which are help writing code in these frameworks.
I found http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angularjs-eclipse#.U9VZpXWSxCU, but It does not work with coffeescript (or maybe I do not know how to configure it).
When I open .coffee file in angular editor I can see only plain text without any highlights and content assist.
How to configure eclipse to work with these frameworks? Or maybe is another IDE for angularjs, coffeescript in playframework structure?

Thanks for replies and sorry for my english.

Comment: What do yo mean by saying "in playframework structure" ?

Comment: I mean this structure http://postimg.org/image/3r3e0v5n5/
As you can see the controller is just plain text.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I use Sublime Text 2, which you can download from [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)..

You can then add some plugin to support those framework..

- Coffescript: https://github.com/Xavura/CoffeeScript-Sublime-Plugin
- AngularJS: https://github.com/angular-ui/AngularJS-sublime-package
- Play: https://github.com/guillaumebort/play2-sublimetext2

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

I tried to Sublime Text 2, when I installed all plugins and then I tried add "Recommended Settings", Sublime showed me popup "Buy license".
Finally I removed .coffee files and I wrote the controllers in pure js.
When the controllers are written in pure js, everything is ok.

I installed this plug of https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse, then I configured it.
After configuration I added in properties project path to folder where I have js files (right click on the project -> Properties -> Tern -> Script paths)

Result:

- js content assist http://s30.postimg.org/cqftgkpmp/image.png
- html content assist http://s12.postimg.org/l586ejryl/html.png

Answer (score 0):

[AngularJS Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse) is based on **tern.js** which is an inference JavaScript engine. So it works today only with JavaScript. Some people have started to support CoffeScript with tern, but it seems that it's not perfect. See [this issue](https://github.com/marijnh/tern/issues/226)

For CoffeScript editor, I suggest you to install http://www.nodeclipse.org/coffeescript/

If one day tern.js supports well CoffeScript, I think it should be a good idea to :

1. integrates tern-coffescript to tern.java (AngularJS Eclipse is based on tern.java).
2. integrates tern.java to http://www.nodeclipse.org/coffeescript/ to benefit with CoffeScript completion managed by tern.js

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse 4.4.0 with Aptana Studio 3 Plugin. Use the following URL as location: http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/update/
It supports syntax coloring and some kind of shortcuts ("Commands") but no content assist.